# spring (postgres, jpa, rest) - how to execute function (StoredProcedure) and return results in rest

Tags: spring, postgresql, function, rest, jpa

I am struggling with spring lately. I have working postgres database. I also have working really simple spring server - model + repository. Model's classes with `@Entity` and repository's classes with `@RepositoryRestResource`. Basically I have something like in this tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/

Now I have function (or stored procedure - I don't know because postgres doesn't support `CREATE PROCEDURE` syntax) in postgres which returns table (custom data types - not alike any table in database).
I would like to execute that function (it takes a little longer than a few seconds - like 60 seconds) with my parameters and of course give back result through rest (in any type - json / xml / raw text).

I am newbie as comes to spring and I would appreciate any solution / advice / tutorial / blog post that solves my problem.

Thanks up front,
James

Comment: that function that takes a little "longer than a few seconds" to run, will it be executed very often? it do just querys (selects) or it does other things (inserts, updates, deletes)? can you "cache" its results to a table optimized for the query of your REST service/api?

Comment: @MarceloBezerra , well, it doesn't inserts, updates or deletes but beside selecting it does a lot of calculations. (A* algorithm multiple times) so I can't really store/cache it in temporary table. I can create temp table and inserts the result there if you want to execute func and then simple get the data. And at the beginning of function I would simple erase all data from temp table.